# Android mediaplayer won't load Uri with path /documents/audio:1159

Tags: java, android, audio, android-intent, android-studio

I'm trying to play audio files with the built in mediaplayer in Android Studio. I'm using the code below to call an intent and open a third party file manager to get a files Uri and from that the file path whoich I store somewhere. Anyway, if I use a file manager like ES File Explorer I get a path that looks like "/sdcard/some directory/test.mp3" however, if I use the built in file explorer I get a path like "/documents/audio:1159" for the same file. I understand that the latter is an "asset" but when I try to feed this into mediaplayer I get an exception. What am I doing wrong?

The code below shows the intent method I'm using to get the filepath and the code below that shows how I use that file path to get a Uri and feed this into mediaplayer. Just to be clear file paths like "/sdcard/some directory/test.mp3" work fine. File paths like "/documents/audio:1159" don't.

```
final View.OnClickListener mGlobal_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(final View v) {

    int resID2 = v.getId();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent,resID2); }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please install a file manager",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    Uri data = result.getData();
    String thePath = data.getPath();
    // Do something with the file path
}
```

}

Code used to start mediaplayer based on the file path retrieved from above

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();    
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();  
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot use Uri like

> /documents/audio:1159

when uses Intent MediaPlayer

EDITTED: 
Try this code for getting filepath from assets folder

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open(file:///android_asset/myfoldername/myfilename);
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way around this? Can I convert the assets path to an actual file path perhaps? Or is there a different way of feeding this into the mediaplayer?

Comment: Very interesting. Will give this a try tonight.

Comment: Couldn't seem to get this to work in Android studio but anyway... Appreciate the help. Its almost certainly me.